# Graph parabola in matplotlib with vertex and 2 'end' points known

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, graphing

Trying to create a parabolic vector of values where the Vertex and two other points along the parabola are known.

Example...

- Range from 0 to 10
- Vertex = [5,2]
- Coordinate 1 = [1,1]
- Coordinate 2=  [10,1]

[image: Example Desired result]

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use numpy to adjust a parabola passing by the points with `polyfit`, and then `polyval` to evaluate the polynomial found:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#points
x = [1, 5, 10]
y = [1, 2, 1]

poly_coeffs = np.polyfit(x,y,2) #fit a polynomial with degree=2

#evaluation points vector xx
xmin = 0
xmax = 10
xx = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
yy = np.polyval(poly_coeffs, xx) #y coords

#ploting
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y,'or')
plt.plot(xx,yy)
plt.grid()
plt.ylim([-3,4])
plt.xlim([-0.5,12])
```

This would draw the next image:

[image]